# equivalence matlab code in c ++ opencv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, opencv3.0

I basically like to know the equivalent of the following code in matlab to opencv using c ++

MascMmax = s3 > Mmax

This compares all positions of the two matrices and to fulfill the condition wards 1 and 0 otherwise.

In opencv I found that I can do but I saved 255, 0. I wonder how I do like 1 and 0.

example:

```
a [1,2,3]
b [2,1,4]

c = a > b

c[0,1,0]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do..

Comment: How about divide by 255?

Comment: Thanks, Run!!!!  , thank you so much!!!  I had not thought of that

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the function [`compare()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) performs the per-element comparison of two arrays or an array and scalar value.

You can have the following comparisons:

- `CMP_EQ` `src1` is equal to `src2`.
- `CMP_GT` `src1` is greater than `src2`.
- `CMP_GE` `src1` is greater than or equal to `src2`.
- `CMP_LT` `src1` is less than `src2`.
- `CMP_LE` `src1` is less than or equal to `src2`.
- `CMP_NE` `src1` is unequal to `src2`.

When the comparison result is `true`, the corresponding element of output array is set to 255. The comparison operations can be replaced with the equivalent matrix expressions:

```
Mat dst1 = src1 >= src2;
Mat dst2 = src1 < 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a function like this in Opencv, but you could do the following:

a) compute c as a-b using

```
addWeighted(a,1,b,-1,0,c).
```

addWeighted checks the ranges of your datatype, so for your 8UC1-Data, all negative values will be mapped to zero so that all points with a[i] <= b[i], you will have c[i] = 0, otherwise c[i] > 0
b) use cv::threshold to set all positive entries in c to a fixed value, in your case

```
cv::threshold(c,0,1,THRESH_BINARY)
```

The 0 is your threshold and 1 the value to which all pixels with a value larger than 0 (your threshold) are set.

If you have a signed datatype, the approach will work exactly the same :)